# How to have a figure put in new page and follow by new section?

Tags: positioning

I want to have a second section start right after a figure in first section of thesis.

i am using `\clearpage` after the figure

The output:
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
tesing testing tesing testing tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

tesing testing

\begin{figure}[!b]
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
          \end{figure}
    %

\clearpage

\section{two}
 testing

\end{document}
```

I want to have:

[image]

Comment: If you use `\clearpage\section{two}` the second section will be in another page, so not together the figure.

Comment: Move `\clearpage` before the figure and use `\begin{figure}[t]` to have the figure at the top page. So, `\clearpage\begin{figure}[t]...\end{figure} \section{two}`

Comment: @Sigur. Thanks. it worked. How about `\begin{figure}[h!}`? I saw other thesis template all use `\begin{figure}[h!}`. it work out the same.